# Reading C# Custom Attributes in MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute defined in the AssemblyInfo.cs file for a C# assembly, and I would like to read the value of this custom attribute during the MSBuild process.  I already have a somewhat hacky solution which reads the AssemblyInfo.cs file and gets the attribute value via RegEx, but this has some downsides e.g. the attribute is commented out but still matches the RegEx pattern.

I see there is an AssemblyInfo MSBuild task, but it seems to only support reading non-custom attributes from a dll.  Is there some way I can extract the custom attribute value directly from the dll?  I am also open to any other solutions that are less brittle than parsing the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  I would also prefer to avoid writing my own custom task to do this because we have no other custom tasks, and having a custom task assembly with one task seems like overkill.

Comment: Is the custom attribute defined in the same assembly you're trying to extract it from?

Comment: Yes, the AssemblyInfo.cs which contains the custom attribute is part of that same assembly.

Comment: That makes the problem slightly harder because you'll need to use reflection to extract the attribute's values. Regarding the custom task, you can use inline tasks to avoid having a custom task assembly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx.

Comment: That would work for my case.  We are already using reflection to read the attribute elsewhere so it shouldn't be too much work, though it won't be pretty =).